# Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html

There are many other questions here about this exact same error however i didn't find a solution in any of them.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ChatRoom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="./">
                <h1>ChatRoom</h1>
                <h3>Basic Chatroom<h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="joinForm">
            <div class="tHeader">
                <h2>Join A ChatRoom</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="formArea">
                <form action="joinRoom.php" method="GET">
                    <h3>Name Of Room:</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="roomName" class="jmInput" placeholder="Name Of Room">
                    <h3 class="margin-top">Password:</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="roomName" class="jmInput" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="submit" name="roomName" class="jmInput" value="Join ChatRoom">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS:

```
window.onload = fadeIn();

function fadeIn() {
var el = document.getElementById('joinForm');
el.style.opacity = 0;

(function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if(!((val += .1) > 1)) {
        el.style.opacity = val;
        requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
})();
}
```

Apparently somehow document.getElementById('joinForm') is null. I really have no idea how i should fix this.

Any help will be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload = fadeIn();` **calls** `fadeIn` and assigns its return value to `window.onload`, exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`. So your `fadeIn` isn't waiting for the `load` event. So presumably the element you're looking up with `getElementById` doesn't exist yet, and so `getElementById` returns `null`.

Remove the `()` to assign the function reference:

```
window.onload = fadeIn;
```

---

Side note: The `load` event happens **very** late in the page load process, waiting for all images and other external resources to load. Usually you just want to put your `script` tag at the very bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and run your function immediately — it'll have access to all of the elements, because they're defined above it. But if you have a reason for waiting for `load`, just remove the `()`.